# How to access SharePoint Online User Profile Pictures from out side of SharePoint?

Tags: asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-userprofile

I have created a dot net core application with Angular to get SharePoint data from outside of SharePoint.

I have used the below link as a reference,

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/consume-sharepoint-online-csom-rest-api-with-dotnet-core-3-1/

I have successfully got data from SharePoint online list. I have a few confusion which are added below,

I will need to display SharePoint Online users' profile pictures based on user email or any alternative way on my public site page.

Also, I have added images to SharePoint Online List/Library. How can I retrieve those images on my public site page?

Can anyone help me with the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that you had a public site page, so I think what you need is a website which displays many users' profile picture. Hence, client credential flow may be a good option for you which has the ability to get all users' profile from graph api.

Here's the code sample to get profile picture.

```
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var tenantId = "your_tenant_name.onmicrosoft.com";
var clientId = "azure_ad_client_id";
var clientSecret = "client_secret";
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
                tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
var user = await graphClient.Users["{user-id}"].Photo.Request().GetAsync();
```

You may check the response and here's the [api doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0#get-the-photo).
And the sharepoint site images, you may follow [this api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request).
`/sites/{site-id}/drive/items/{item-id}`